# "Neverending" TakeWhile, BufferWhile and SkipWhile RX.Net Sequences

Tags: .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I was wondering whether there is a way to take an observable stream and use the *While operators, particularly TakeWhile, SkipWhile and BufferWhile, so that subscribers to them do not receive an .OnComplete when the bool 'while' condition is fullfilled?

When I started using the .TakeWhile / SkipWhile and BufferWhile operators I assumed that they wouldn't terminate / .OnComplete() but merely (not) emit while the bool condition is met.

It might make more sense with an example:

I have a bool flag that indicates i.e. whether an instance is busy or not and an Observable stream of data:

```
private bool IsBusy { get;set; }
private bool IgnoreChanges { get;set; }

private IObservable<int> Producer { get;set; }
private IDisposable ConsumerSubscription { get;set; }
```

.. and use / setup the RX stream(s) like that (simplified)

```
private void SetupRx()
{
    ConsumerSubscription = Producer
        .SkipWhile(_ => IgnoreChanges == true) // Drop the producer's stream of ints whenever the IgnoreChanges flag is set to true, but forward them whenever the IgnoreChanges flag is set to false
        .BufferWhile(_ => IsBusy == true) // for all streamed instances buffer them as long as we are busy handling the previous one(s)
        .Subscribe(i => DoSomething(i));
}

private void DoSomething(int i)
{
    try
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        // ... do something
    }
    finally
    {
        IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

The .SkipeWhile/.BufferWhile should not complete / OnComplete(..) whenever the IsBusy/IgnoreChanges flags switch from true to false and back but keep the stream alive.

Is that somehow doable with RX.Net out of the box and/or does someone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Just to clarify, there is no BufferWhile in RX.net (my mistake)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To drop the `OnCompleted` message from an `IObservable<T>` source, simply `Concat` with `Observable.Never<T>()`:

```
source.TakeWhile(condition).Concat(Observable.Never<T>())
```

---

To manually subscribe to an `IObservable<T>` source such that the subscription is ended only when you manually unsubscribe, you can use `Publish` and `IConnectableObservable<T>`:

```
var connectableSource = source.Publish();
// To subscribe to the source:
var subscription = connectableSource.Connect();
...
// To unsubscribe from the source:
subscription.Dispose();
```

---

All of that being said, I think you are approaching this incorrectly. If it is done correctly, you won't need the above tricks. Look at your query:

```
ConsumerSubscription = Producer
    // Drop the producer's stream of ints whenever the IgnoreChanges flag
    // is set to true, but forward them whenever the IgnoreChanges flag is set to false
    .SkipWhile(_ => IgnoreChanges == true) 
    // For all streamed instances buffer them as long as we are busy
    // handling the previous one(s)
    .BufferWhile(_ => IsBusy == true) 
    .Subscribe(i => DoSomething(i));
```

You should be using `.Where(_ => !IgnoreChanges)` instead of `.SkipWhile(_ => IgnoreChanges)`.

You should be using `.Buffer(_ => IsBusy.SkipWhile(busy => busy))` with a `BehaviorSubject<bool> IsBusy` instead of `.BufferWhile(_ => IsBusy)`.

The complete code would look like this:

```
private BehaviorSubject<bool> IsBusy { get;set; }
private bool IgnoreChanges { get;set; }

private IObservable<int> Producer { get;set; }
private IDisposable ConsumerSubscription { get;set; }

private void SetupRx()
{
    ConsumerSubscription = Producer
        .Where(_ => !IgnoreChanges)
        .Buffer(_ => IsBusy.SkipWhile(busy => busy))
        .Subscribe(buffer => DoSomething(buffer));
}

private void DoSomething(IList<int> buffer)
{
    try
    {
        IsBusy.OnNext(true);
        // Do something
    }
    finally
    {
        IsBusy.OnNext(false);
    }
}
```

---

The next improvement would be to try to get rid of the `BehaviorSubject<bool> IsBusy`. Subjects are something you want to try to avoid because they are state you have to manage.

Comment: Thanks Timothy for the hint regarding simplifying my thoughts a little! I noticed that there isn't a BufferWhile in RX at all so I fiddled a little and wrote three Extension methods for my three use-cases: https://github.com/jbattermann/JB.Common/blob/master/JB.Common.Reactive/Linq/ObservableExtensions.cs ... SkipWhile/TakeWhile were actually quite easy to write, not really happy with (my) .BufferWhile just yet, but oh well.. But in general - thanks for the reply and clarifications / pointers towards Publish, Where etc. Cheers!